# Mapping functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is a sample homework question I have.

Match the following functions from naturals to naturals with the properties they have.

f(x) = x + 1 if x is even, f(x) = x + 2 if x is odd

a) both onto and one to one
b) one to one but not onto
c) onto but not one to one
d) not onto and not one to one

I understand what one to one and onto are by drawing but I dont see how to set up this question. Are both input and output elements 0 thru n?

Comment: If it is onto, you need to show that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is some $x$ so that $f(x)=n$.  What happens when $n=1$ or $n=2$?  It is one-to-one if $f(x)\neq f(y)$ whenever $x\neq y$.  What is $f(1)$? what is $f(2)$?

Comment: naturals are all numbers not including fractions, or negative but including 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = x + 1$ if $x$ is even$ ,(2k+\color{red}{1}$) , $f(x) = x + 2$ if $x$ is odd,($2k+1+{2}=\color{red}{2k'+1}$) thus image is always odd thus it isnot onto.

**for more information**

if $f(x) = x + 1$ if $x$ is even , $f(x) = x + 2$ if $x$ is odd.
suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ if both $x$ and $y$ be even then $f(x)=x+1=y+1=f(y)$ gives $x=y$ similarly if both be odd. but if $x$ even and $y$ odd, $$f(x)=x+1=y-1=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y-2$$ imposible since $y-2$ is odd and $x$ is even.

suppose  $a$ has given if a be even $f(x)=x+1=a$ for some even $x$. impossible right hand is odd and left hand even.
 $f(x)=x-1=a$ for some even $x$. so $x=a+1$ is ok
....

Comment: Ok. So if it were f(x) = x+1m and f(x) = x-1, then it would be odd and even thus both onto  and one to one?

Comment: for find is it one to one or not, you have to  suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ then show that $x=y$ or not. for similar question, see what happens if both of $x,y$ be even or odd or one even and one odd. similarly to show that it is onto, suppose $a_0$ see it is even or odd and $f$ can produce it or not. here for your example it dependes on m. in both case.

Comment: I'm sorry the m was a typo. It is just x+1 and x-1

Comment: @Varoag I add some things  in my answer. I hope it help you